# Sum of calculation in a variable

Tags: python, calculator

I am stuck on how to make a calculation in a variable. Currently my code will print (for example) : (1,'+',2). But I need the actual sum of the answer.. My code:

```
def calc(num1,op,num2):
    sum = num1,op,num2
    print(sum)

num1 = int(input("First number:"))
op = input("Operator:")
num2 = int(input("Second number:"))

calc(num1,op,num2)
```

Comment: I think it's not an evidence for OP that it is  a duplicate.  the key is that  `+` (the symbol) and `add` (the function) are different things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can help you.....

```
def calc(x=0, y=0, z=0):
    expression = raw_input('Enter an expression: ')

    return eval(expression, None, locals())
```

Example:

```
>>> calc()
Enter an expression: 8 + 5 - 7
6
```

Comment: `eval` is really not a good choice here. This is a good explanation that might interest you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1832957/1832539